# Unable to run Ubuntu in VM due to AMD-V not available

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox on Windows 10. I have setup the BIOS to enable virtualisation. Based on looking at Task Manager's Performance tab, I can see that the Virtualisation is enabled. I have gone to the 'Turn Windows feature on or off' and turned off Hyper-V + reset PC (also tried with keeping it ticked and reset PC, same outcome). In the VM, I have also ticked the Enable VT-x/AMD-V hardware virtualization under the systems settings.

I am trying to run Ubuntu in the VM (Click start and install) but unable to with following error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04.4

(VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API).
AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Looked around for similar issues and the steps recommended have been followed as mentioned above. I still end up with the same error message. Please advice what might be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I use Hyper-V to run virtual box on my windows machine so not sure why that should be turned off

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Seen examples on YT videos askign to disable it. In any case tried with it turned on and off. Same outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyper V needs to be turned off in my case. My virtualization was enabled in BIOS. 
I had to go in disable the virtualization save it. Then during reboot go back into BIOS again to enable virtualization again. Now after Reboot in Windows, VM is working with no issues.

Don't think it matters but for reference, using a MSI Tomahawk B450 MAx motherboard. Weird for the need to switch the virtualization off and on again. But it worked for me. Hope it helps someone in similar situation.